# cannot find package "appengine/cloudsql"

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I develop some GO libraries using Google Cloud SQL and MySQL server. When I imported `appengine/cloudsql, an error below occured.

`cloud.go:20:2: cannot find package "appengine/cloudsql" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.1.2/src/pkg/appengine/cloudsql (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/lameduck/myGo/src/appengine/cloudsql (from $GOPATH)`

I know this package, `appengine/cloudsql`, is only for Google App Engine and it doesn't exist on everywhere else.

I'm wondering how can I use it for GAE and standard sql library for other environments in a single library.

PS: I can setup Google App Engine SDK correctly. My question is not relevant to it. I hope my library runs on Google App Engine and standalone environment together. (I already made a code for GAE and a code for other dabatases.) It is Ok that users have to setup some configurations. But I don't want that users have to modify a library source code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/devenvironment . It looks like the Go AppEngine SDK may not be installed.

Comment: There's also a link (but no content) regarding "Using a local MySQL instance during development" at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/#Go_Using_a_local_MySQL_instance_during_development so I'd say this is being worked on now.

Comment: Thanks @Intermernet. But my question is not relevant to setup GAE SDK.

I'm developing a library which uses Google Cloud SQL or standard SQL servers. If the library runs on Google App Engine, it runs correctly. Otherwise, an error occured. I'm wondering how can I isolate GAE code and other things to avoid that error.

Comment: @Intermernet, Unfortunately, "Using a local MySQL instance during development" is not written by Google yet.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a single library, but it would be fairly easy to do in two libraries. Reading your reply to @mjibson it would seem that you're probably already doing the correct thing by separating the db code into a different package. As far as I know you can't successfully import the GAE packages outside of GAE or the standalone environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. I used a [build constraint](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to use the proper routine and avoid an error. There is a build constraint for App Engine, [appengine](http://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath).

> The App Engine SDK introduces a new build constraint term:
>   "appengine". Files that specify
>
> // +build appengine will be built by the App Engine SDK and ignored by
>   the go tool. Conversely, files that specify
>
> // +build !appengine are ignored by the App Engine SDK, while the go
>   tool will happily build them.

PS:
Anway, I upvoted other answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Package import is done during compile/link time. And Go doesn't support runtime conditional imports in distinction from Python.

Feature you are looking for is dynamic library loading (like in C/C++ you can load .so/.dll in runtime), but Go currently [doesn't support it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8xP5dKf0LJc).