# build constraint app engine golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Im pretty new to go and to the the app engine ,

I got this error **cannot find package "appengine"** .

so i researched a little bit and i found out about  build constraint
[cannot find package "appengine/cloudsql"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852395/cannot-find-package-appengine-cloudsql)

I tried to solve it by this commands .

```
 go build  -v -tags  +build appengine
```

But i got the same  error **package appengine: cannot find package "appengine"** .

I can run the  goapp server and deploy app to the app engine

But i cant build or get the auto complete of the app engine library

thanks,

miki

Comment: You must use `goapp` to build code that depends on the appengine packages. The standard `go` tool does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `-tags appengine`, and in the file that needs to just work on appengine you can start it with:

```
// +build appengine

package someName
```

Comment: I added the // +build appengine as you suggested but i got the same result

Comment: @MIkCode like BeBop said, you have to use `goapp`